# StreamSets upgrade and LDAP authentication

Tags: cloudera-manager, streamsets

Just upgraded StreamSets from 2.1.0.2 to 2.4.0.0 using Cloudera Manager (5.8.2). I can't login anymore into StreamSets - I get "login failed". The new version seem to be using a different LDAP lookup method.

My logs **BEFORE** Update looks as below:

Mar 15, 10:42:07.799 AM              INFO      com.streamsets.datacollector.http.LdapLoginModule
Searching for users with filter: '(&(objectClass={0})({1}={2}))' from base dn: DC=myComp,DC=Statistics,DC=ComQ,DC=uk
Mar 15, 10:42:07.826 AM              INFO      com.streamsets.datacollector.http.LdapLoginModule
Found user?: true
Mar 15, 10:42:07.826 AM              INFO      com.streamsets.datacollector.http.LdapLoginModule
Attempting authentication: CN=UserDV,OU=London,OU=ComQ,DC=ComQ,DC=Statistics,DC=comQ,DC=uk

My logs **AFTER** Update looks as below:

Mar 15, 11:10:21.406 AM              INFO      com.streamsets.datacollector.http.LdapLoginModule
Accessing LDAP Server: ldaps://comQ.statisticsxxx.com:3269 startTLS: false
Mar 15, 11:10:22.086 AM              INFO      org.ldaptive.auth.SearchDnResolver
search for user=[org.ldaptive.auth.User@1573608120::identifier= userdv, context=null] failed using filter=[org.ldaptive.SearchFilter@1129802876::filter=(&(objectClass=user)(uid={user})), parameters={context=null, user=userdv}]
Mar 15, 11:10:22.087 AM              INFO      com.streamsets.datacollector.http.LdapLoginModule
Found user?: false
Mar 15, 11:10:22.087 AM              ERROR  com.streamsets.datacollector.http.LdapLoginModule
Result code: null - DN cannot be null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change `ldap.userFilter` in Cloudera Manager from `uid={user}` to `name={user}`